# How to send email with attachments in WinUI app?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

My application is a WinUI desktop application using .Net 6.

```xml
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
```

I thought I could use the [EmailManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email#related-topics) from UWP (which supports email attachments) but I get the following error when I do.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070032): The request is not supported. (0x80070032)
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.IEmailManagerStaticsMethods.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(IObjectReference _obj, EmailMessage message)
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(EmailMessage message)
   at WinUIApp.MainWindow.ComposeEmail(String subject, String messageBody)
```

**What is the correct API to use to send emails from a WinUI application?**

#### Code

I made the application using the [default WinUI template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app) and simply added the following code in `MainWindows.xaml.cs` to test.

```cs
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myButton.Content = "Clicked";

    ComposeEmail("Bob", "Hello Bob.");
}

private async Task ComposeEmail(string subject, string messageBody)
{
    try
    {
        var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Note that the previous code works fine in a UWP app. It launches the Mail app. I was expecting it to do the same in my WinUI app, but it doesn't.

Comment: According to this doc [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmessage.attachments?view=winrt-22621) emailMessage has an Attachment property that you can interact with.

Comment: You did not copy the complete example from learn.microsoft.com. You are getting errors because you left out some important parts.....

Comment: @Luuk I don't think so. This exact same code works fine in a UWP app. It correctly launches the Mail app.
@CGA I know. The problem is that `EmailManager` doesn't work at all (with or without attachments).

Comment: Then it's probably: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab5341e6-27fb-4eb2-97b0-57257a579bed/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x80070032?forum=xamarinvisualstudio

Answer (score 2):

The EmailManager API is only supported with UWP apps, because it depends on [Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow)'s [GetForCurrentThread  method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getforcurrentthread) which [always get backs null for non-UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#apis-that-have-dependencies-on-uwp-only-ui-features).

You can check this dependency if you disassemble the `ShowComposeNewEmailAsync` function, as shown in this screenshot here:

[image]

Some of these WinRT classes have been modified to support the [IInitializeWindow trick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/winrt-com-interop-csharp#code-example) to support classical HWNDs, but it seems it's not the case here. Maybe you can report that to Microsoft so they can improve it.

So you'll have to find other non-WinRT/UWP ways to send email.